# Postmap returns database not found error

Tags: mysql, postfix

I have set up my Postfix configuration with Mysql maps, prety much as detailed  [here](https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie/postfix-mysql) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin).

I have a file at /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf which contains the following:

> ```
>  user = mailuser
>  password = fLxsWdf5ABLqwhZr
>  hosts = 127.0.0.1
>  dbname = mailserver
>  query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_domains WHERE name='%s'
> ```

this is linked to in the /etc/postfix/main.cf with the following line:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
```

When I use postmap

```
postmap -qv dave@example.co.za mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: open database dave@example.co.za.db: No such file or directory
```

Clearly there is no database "dave@example.co.za.db" but I'm expecting it to look in the "mailserver" database.

Additional info ~~~~~~~~~~~
Just adding this to rule out the chances of a typo (the dave@ was a typo above):

```
sudo cat /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf 
user = mailuser
password = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mailserver
query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_domains WHERE name='%s'
dave@server:~$ postmap -qv example.co.za mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
postmap: fatal: open database example.co.za.db: No such file or directory
dave@server:~$
```

.
Checking that the query works:

> ```
>  mysql -u mailuser -p
>  Enter password: 
>  Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>  Your MariaDB connection id is 1922
>  Server version: 10.1.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu 18.04
> ```

```
 Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

 Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

 MariaDB [(none)]> connect mailserver
 Reading table information for completion of table and column names
 You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

 Connection id:    1923
 Current database: mailserver

 MariaDB [mailserver]> SELECT 1 FROM virtual_domains WHERE name='example.co.za';
 +---+
 | id | name            |
 +---+
 |  6 | example.co.za |
 +---+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just made a typo. It should be `postmap -q`, not `postmap -qv`.

Comment: The -qv is for verbose. If I simply use -q, then it just returns with no error message.

Comment: @DaveCoventry No, it's a typo. If you want verbose, you need to specify `-v` separately. Otherwise it is treated as an argument to `-q`.

Comment: Ok, I'll certainly try that. The website I got it from stipulated that it was appended to the -q argument, but I'm happy to test it.

Comment: That would hardly be the first error in an Internet tutorial.

Comment: Same result, though. I'm a bit baffled.